# How to create a function that returns a promise in NodeJs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise

[EDIT : since this is a basic question which expects a basic answer,

### I added my own answer below, in the question itself

. For more complete information, follow the "duplicate" [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32835472/how-to-use-promises-in-node-4-x), or [this helpful example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33051270/promises-basics-how-to-promisify-async-node-code) provided in the comments]

---

### QUESTION :

---

I have recently learned how to use promises, and I am very happy because now I can avoid callbacks in my asynchronous code :

```js
asyncFunction1()
.then(asyncFunction2)
.then(asyncFunction3)
.catch( (err) => {/*handle*/} );
```

But I am limited to USING those asynchronous functions. Now I want to CREATE my own asynchronous functions when needed :

```js
myCustomAsyncFunction() 
.then(asyncFunction1)  // asyncFunction1 expects a String parameter : "customResult"
.catch( (err) => {/*handle*/} );

function myCustomAsyncFunction() {
  
  // do an async operation
  // and when finished :
  
  return("customResult");
}
```

The previous snippet leads to an error : `myCustomAsyncFunction` doesn't have a property `.then()` attached to it.

Question : how can I properly and efficiently make my function a part of the "promise chain" ?

---

### ANSWER :

---

In the promise world, an asynchronous function returns a promise instead of the `customResult` you are thinking of.

If you do not know what a deferred object and its attached promise are, a good video explaining the principles of promises can be found [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=104J7_HyaG4&list=LLIvlkL0Mn3jQlr7wca7JS2A).

Now, let's assume you have grasped the basic concepts. If we want our `customFunction` to return a promise, we have to build it, following [this good tutorial](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/) :

```js
var myCustomPromise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  
  // the async code of myCustomFunction

  if (/* everything turned out fine */) {
    resolve("someResult");
  }
  else {
    reject(Error("someError"));
  }
});
```

The new promise will immediately run the anonymous function you specify as a parameter. The promise object will then "wait" for the anonymous function to call either `resolve` or `reject`. Those two *functions* are triggers :

- if `resolve("someResult")` is called by your code, any .then() attached to the promise will fire, and take `"someResult"` as the value to pass down the chain.
- if `reject(Error("someError"))`, the .catch() will fire...

All right, this is fun, but declaring a new promise fires my async code immediately. If I want to fire it at will, I must wrap all of the above in a function :

```js
function myCustomFunction() { 
  
    return new Promise( function(resolve, reject) { 
       
        // the async code of myCustomFunction

        if (/* everything turned out fine */) {
            resolve("someResult");
        }
        else {   
            reject(Error("someError"));
        }   
    }); 
}
```

Here is the expected chain of events with this code :

1. Whenever called, `myCustomFunction` will immediately return a new pending promise.
2. This brand new pending promise will fire immediately your async code.
3. At some point, your async code should call either `resolve()` or `reject()`.
4. This will give the promise its final status and value.
5. Any .then() or .catch() listening to the promise will know what to do !

Comment: `function myAsync() { return new Promise( function(fulfill, reject ) { /* your code */ fulfill( someVariable ); } ) }`

Comment: Alternative existing question/answer which is more code oriented: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33051270/promises-basics-how-to-promisify-async-node-code

Comment: @Quentin : The duplicate you link to basically links to the documentations. I have already tried reading most of those pages and I think they are very unwelcoming for beginners. I asked this question this way also because I think it could speed up future beginners. I am ready to answer the question myself for others.

Comment: @KLôN — It's still a duplicate even if you don't like the answers. You can give a better answer on the duplicate question if you like.